# Magento RMA plugin issue

Tags: magento-1.9, plugin

I'm just wondering why this plugin seems to be requesting a resource through http on a site that is fully https forced.

[image]

I am fully baffled on how this is happening seeing that there is no reference to http within the plugins code as far as I can see.

Essentially, my question is if there is a way to redirect this request to https somehow through magento as the XMLHTTPRquest seems to try request an unsecure piece of content.

Comment: Can you share the code where do you think its requesting that data from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you didn't found `http` reference in plugin code is because they might be set AJAX request URL using `Mage::getBase()` or anything relevant to that.

However, you can quick fix this using `prototype` `onCreate` event handler. Put below code in your theme `footer.phtml` file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Ajax.Responders.register({
            onCreate: function(request) {
                if (location.protocol === 'https:') {
                    request.url = request.url.replace("http:", "https:");
                }
            }
        });
</script>
```

What it does? This will bind event and triggered when `prototype` AJAX object has been created. It will verify your site URL, if it is `https:` then replace your AJAX URL with `https:`.

Please not that this is quick fix for your issue and applied to all of your AJAX request which is initialize through `prototype`.

Let me know if you have any query regarding this solution.

Answer (score 0):

This come to form of Order Grid. 
 Essentialy check **Magento -> Settings -> Web -> Secure**. Check web *Secure use in frontend* to **ENABLE**. It's force all form to use https protocol. It's needed to enable, even if you force url in other places.